# Code is not update in Maven war

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC and Hibernate Project.When i build war clean install and deploy in tomact.In console old code is running Means like this is my index controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/index" })
public class IndexController {

 private final Logger logger = 
   LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(ModelMap model, final Principal principal) {
    //logger.debug("Enter in Get method IndexController");

    return "index";
  }
}
```

you can see i comment the logger but it print in console.So i think it comes from another controller then i delete all controllers from my code and after deploying  it still print logger and i also remove logger from this controller and after deploying  it still print logger.I dont know why my code is not update in war.Can anyone help me

Comment: You may need to rebuild the artifacts too before rebuilding the war file.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how can do this.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please clear local repository and then do `clean install`

For windows you can find `.m2` repository in your `C:\Users\{yourUsername}\.m2`